# Issue swith jquery multiselect plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using jquery multiselct plug-in https://plugins.jquery.com/multi-select/

In one scenario I need to select some default values and then disable them so no one can remove them.Below is my code where i have made some options selected based on some condition.

```
  $('#members_select3').find('option').remove().end()
    $.each(response.results, function (i, item) {
                        $('#members_select3').append($('<option>', { 
                            selected: function(){
                                if (**condition comes here**){
                                        return true;
                            },
                            value: item.uid,
                            text : item.contact,
                        }));
                    });

  enable_multi_select_search('members_select3');
```

Now as per docs if i use disable option in above code the option becomes disable but it is not selected any-more means the option is available for selection rather then default selected.

```
$('#members_select3').find('option').remove().end()
$.each(response.results, function (i, item) {
    $('#members_select3').append($('<option>', { 
        selected: function(){
            if (**condition comes here**){
                    return true;
            }
        },
        value: item.uid,
        text : item.contact,
        disabled: function(){
            if (**condition comes here**){
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }));
});

enable_multi_select_search('members_select3');
```

**Default function of plug-in n**

```
function enable_multi_select_search(id_){
    // refresh previous multi select box
    $('#members_select3').multiSelect("destroy");

    // create new
    $('#'+id_).multiSelect({
        selectableHeader: "<input type='text' class='form-control search-input' autocomplete='off' placeholder='search...'>",
        selectionHeader: "<input type='text' class='form-control search-input' autocomplete='off' placeholder='search...'>",
        afterInit: function (ms) {
            var that = this,
                $selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev(),
                $selectionSearch = that.$selectionUl.prev(),
                selectableSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
                selectionSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';

            that.qs1 = $selectableSearch.quicksearch(selectableSearchString)
                .on('keydown', function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 40) {
                        that.$selectableUl.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            that.qs2 = $selectionSearch.quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
                .on('keydown', function (e) {
                    if (e.which == 40) {
                        that.$selectionUl.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        },
        afterSelect: function () {
            this.qs1.cache();
            this.qs2.cache();
        },
        afterDeselect: function () {
            this.qs1.cache();
            this.qs2.cache();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should distinguish between `disabled` and `readOnly`:

- `disabled`: the option is not selectable, even not as a default
- `readOnly`: the state of the option (selected or not) can not be changed

I guess, you're heading for the second one.

*EDIT*:

Maybe you can change the plugin like this (not tested):

```
       $('#members_select3').append($('<option>', { 
                selected: function(){
                    if (**condition comes here**){
                            return true;
                    }
                },
                value: item.uid,
                text : item.contact,
                disabled: false,
                readOnly: function(){
                    if (**condition comes here**){
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }));
        });
```

Comment: Yes may be but here readonly is not working , It is appended to html but I guess the above plugin do not provide readonly property so may be thats the reason